# Threading Error when Running Vim Plugin (CoVim)

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am trying to use the [CoVim](https://github.com/FredKSchott/CoVim) plugin, which allows for collaborative editing in ViM (like google docs). However, when doing so, I receive the following error:

```
[xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
gvim: ../../src/xcb_io.c:179: dequeue_pending_request: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_unknown_req_in_deq' failed.
Vim: Caught deadly signal ABRT
Vim: Finished.

Successfully disconnected from document!
Exception RuntimeError: RuntimeError('cannot join current thread',) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

According to CoVim's docs:

> **"I get an error that mentions a Python file named "threading.py"**
>   Your current build of Vim won't work with CoVim. CoVim uses threading, and modifying the Vim buffer isn't entirely thread-safe. This isn't a problem in most builds, but there are a few common ones that will cause you problems. The most current build (at time of writing) works with CoVim."

But, as far as I know, I am using the latest build of vim (I ran sudo apt-get install vim, and am using vim 7.4). What could this issue be?

Comment: Update (probably manually). Whats the output of `vim --version`? I think we are up to vim 7.4.898

Comment: Have you tried compiling Vim from scratch?  I found that the Vim packages on recent Linux distros (CentOS and Ubuntu) were compiled without  the "--enable-pythoninterp=dynamic" switch (as part of "./configure").